# Open multiple child windows with one click

Tags: javascript, html, window

I'm trying to open multiple child windows when a single button is clicked. For instance, I have a block labelled "1" and when it is clicked, a corresponding child window with a shockwave flash video plays. However, I want the videos from block 2 and 9 to play as well, as they are next to block 1. Or, if I clicked on 12, the windows for 4, 11, 13, and 20 would appear too, since they surround 12.

Here's the website I'm working with, to give you a better idea.

http://alexalmaguer.site90.com/

This is the code I'm using to get the child window to appear for one video.

```
<a href="1.html," target="ItsAGoodDay" onClick="wopen('1.html', 'ItsAGoodDay', 400, 300); return false;">1</a>
```

1.html just has an object tag with the .swf in it, and a bit of styling to keep the .swf in the middle of the window.

I'm also using a premade script I found on this website to center the child window in the middle of the screen when it opens. I think this might need to be changed as well.

```
<!--
function wopen(url, name, w, h)
{

  w += 32;
  h += 96;
  wleft = (screen.width - w) / 2;
  wtop = (screen.height - h) / 2;

  if (wleft < 0) {
    w = screen.width;
    wleft = 0;
  }
  if (wtop < 0) {
    h = screen.height;
    wtop = 0;
  }
  var win = window.open(url,
    name,
    'width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', ' +
    'left=' + wleft + ', top=' + wtop + ', ' +
    'location=no, menubar=no, ' +
    'status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no');

  win.resizeTo(w, h);

  win.moveTo(wleft, wtop);
  win.focus();
}
```

**EDIT**: Due to limited space, I'm thinking I might just make the windows to the left and right of the selected block open, and not the ones on top and bottom.

Comment: So basically you need `(x+8).html`, `(x-8.html)`, `(x+1).html` and `(x-1).html`,  are there pages static?

Comment: They are static, if that means what I think it does. Where would I implement this code in this scenario? Does that require a new <a> tag? Sorry, I'm kind of a beginner at this.

Comment: On the `onClick` you could call a method passing the number (x) then this method will call `wopen` 5 times passing `x`, `x-1`, `x+1`, `x-8`, `x+8` .html. Of course you will need to verify if the new values x-1, x+1 et. al. fall in the valid range.

Comment: What would this look like in the tag? Also, I don't know how to assign the variable x to the different pages.

Comment: Look at the answer I added below, that should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small script that might help you:

```
<script>
     function myMethod(x){
    alert("Open " + x + ".html");
    if(x-1  > 1) {
        alert("Open " + (x-1) + ".html");
        }
    if(x-8  > 1) {
        alert("Open " + (x-8) + ".html");
    }
    if(x+1  <= 32) {
        alert("Open " + (x+1) + ".html");
        }
    if(x+8  <= 32) {
        alert("Open " + (x+8) + ".html");
    }

     }
</script>
```

Html:

```
<body>
   <a href="#" target="ItsAGoodDay" onClick="myMethod(12)">12</a>
</body>
```

You can play around with this to see if you are getting the desired results.
Then you can replace the alert with `wopen` function passing the html name.

Comment: After a lot of messing around, I'm starting to get it working. Thank you so much for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

To open multiple child windows with one click, do something like this. You just need to call your `wopen` multiple times.

```
function wopen(url, name, w, h) {
w += 32;
h += 96;
wleft = (screen.width - w) / 2;
wtop = (screen.height - h) / 2;

if (wleft < 0) {
    w = screen.width;
    wleft = 0;
}
if (wtop < 0) {
    h = screen.height;
    wtop = 0;
}
var win = window.open(url,
        name,
        'width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', ' +
        'left=' + wleft + ', top=' + wtop + ', ' +
        'location=no, menubar=no, ' +
        'status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no');

win.resizeTo(w, h);

win.moveTo(wleft, wtop);
win.focus();
}

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var win1 = wopen();
    var win2 = wopen();
    var win3 = wopen();
    var win4 = wopen();
    var win5 = wopen();
});
```