# Make child windows appear at random locations

Tags: javascript, html, random, window

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788754/open-multiple-child-windows-with-one-click
```

^^ I just received some help in putting a small website together, and now I have a different idea for it.

http://alexalmaguer.site90.com/

Whenever I click on one of the buttons, up to 5 child windows appear, and they all appear centered on the screen, because of the script below that tells them to do so. This was fine when only one window was opening, but now they all appear on top of each other. Is there any way I can change this to make the windows appear at random locations?

```
function wopen(url, name, w, h)
{

  w += 32;
  h += 96;
  wleft = (screen.width - w) / 2;
  wtop = (screen.height - h) / 2;

  if (wleft < 0) {
    w = screen.width;
    wleft = 0;
  }
  if (wtop < 0) {
    h = screen.height;
    wtop = 0;
  }
  var win = window.open(url, name,
    'width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', ' +
    'left=' + wleft + ', top=' + wtop + ', ' +
    'location=no, menubar=no, ' +
    'status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no');

  win.resizeTo(w, h);

  win.moveTo(wleft, wtop);
  win.focus();
}
```

Comment: Yes. randomise wtop and wleft. I am curious why you open the window in a position and then ALSO move it to the same position afterwards

Comment: Hi Alexander, did you try giving different values to  w, h in the `wopen` function call?

Comment: wtop and wleft, not w and h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. randomise wleft and/or wtop
2. remove spaces in parameters and any =no parameter since that is default.
3. remove needless functions unless they are needed on ancient browsers

---

```
function wopen(url, name, w, h) {

  w += 32;
  h += 96;
  wleft = (screen.width - w) / 2;
  wtop = (screen.height - h) / 2;

  if (wleft < 0) {
    w = screen.width;
    wleft = 0;
  }
  if (wtop < 0) {
    h = screen.height;
    wtop = 0;
  }
  if (wleft > 0) {
    wleft = Math.floor(Math.random() * wleft); // for example
  }
  var win = window.open(url, name,
    'width=' + w + ',height=' + ',left=' + wleft + ',top=' + wtop);

  win.focus();
}
```

Alternative is to not randomise, but remember the coordinates and add the window width each time

Another alternative is to open the window with left and top aligned to the mouse click coordinates